# How to show only filtered views based on selection (drop down)

Tags: customization, tableau-api

I have a scenario, I am working on visualization creation using Tableau. I have set of customers for which I am using a customized views and when individual customer requires report, from the dropdown I select a customer and publish report in pdf format. Now customer wants this visualization to be integrated on their websites. So I got the link from Tableau online by clicking share option and can share with them. 
The problem here, In this situation whole set of reports are available with any customer who asks for it. I do not want to create individual views so is there a way I can select a individual customer from dropdown and share only the filtered views corresponding to the customer?
Thanks

Comment: Do your users have to log in to Tableau?

Comment: no, we do not have individual customer account. But since it is published and on tableau online, we have a master account. I can disable the logging need by changing settings.

Comment: As far as I know; no you cannot do this with one account! One of the main purposes of using multi-accounts is this scenario; you link the accounts to the data dimensions and account owners see only their data within the report.

Comment: Okay, so if I have multiple accounts, how can we link accounts to data dimensions and account owners?